# Need to create a Python Level structure of dictionaries using key value pair

Tags: python, database, data-structures

I'll try my best to explain my problem. Currently I have a dictionary (named level_map) which contains keys and values (the values are the level in which the key should be stored)

Ex:

name: Test
value: 1

name: Test2
value: 2

name: Test3
value: 3

name: Test4
value: 3

should look like this

```
Test
|
|---Test2
      |
      |---Test3
            |
            |---Test4
            |---Test5
```

What my question is, how do I take level_map (my dict obj) and convert it so that it is a dict within a dict for all the different levels because ultimately, I'll be creating a table view on a webpage. I've tried to wrap my head around this and I'm just stuck on where to start. Any starting pointers would be great. Thanks guys.

**EDIT**
Here is how my level_map (dict obj) is structured:

```
level_map = {
  "Test": 1,
  "Test2": 2,
  "Test3": 3,
  "Test4": 4,
  "Test5": 4
}
```

What I want the new dict obj to be is this:

```
new_level_map = {
"Test":{
  "Test2":{
    "Test3": {
        "Test4",
        "Test5"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the real structure of the dictionaries like what it would look like in code? It's not clear how your example even works. We don't know what sort of input we are handling and what kind of output you are expecting.

Comment: I meant your example. What is the exact input you have? To put it plainly, do a `print(level_map)` and show us the output. And also the expected result in actual dictionary format like `{'key1': 'value1'}`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added an edit to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort your dictionary by value and then group them, you can iterate through them from inside to out building the dictionary as you go. `reduce()` is nice for this, but here's a way with a simple loop for clarity. It also uses `operator.itemgetter` to make it a little more readable. You can of course use lambdas if you prefer:

This begins with the the deepest object as a set then continually adds dicts:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)

level_map = {
  "Test": 1,
  "Test2": 2,
  "Test3": 3,
  "Test4": 4,
  "Test5": 4
}

items = sorted(level_map.items(), key=second, reverse=True)
groups = (map(first, g) for _, g in groupby(items, key = second))

curr = set(next(groups)) # deepest

for item in groups:
    curr = {next(item): curr}
print(curr)
```

**prints:**:

```
{'Test': {'Test2': {'Test3': {'Test4', 'Test5'}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the answer.